# GWT RichTextArea in IE

Tags: java, gwt, rich-text-editor

I am having a problem with the GWT RichTextArea (RTA) GWT 2.0 in Internet Explorer 7-8.

The Problem:

I have  GWT richtextarea in closable tabs. I open required tab insert some text(or do not insert) into GWT RTA and then close it. After several times I am not able either to select or to insert text into RTA. Has any of you guys faced with this kind of issue? Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following thread is related to your problem:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/bf95dd80f0d619d

Seems that setting the focus will fix your problem.